# Create Task from button on Custom Object Listview

Tags: javascript, task, apex

I have requirement where I have to create a button on custom object's **list view** , when clicked on that button a task should be created and assigned to a profile name HR.

Behavior of 'Execute Javascript', and content source of 'OnClick Javascript'

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")}

try{
var taskToCreate = new sforce.SObject("Task");

taskToCreate.OwnerId = "{!$User.Id}";
taskToCreate.WhatId = "{!Wage_Register__c}";
taskToCreate.Subject = "Hr Approval";
taskToCreate.ActivityDate = new Date();

taskToCreate.Priority = "Normal";
taskToCreate.Status = "Completed";



result = sforce.connection.create([taskToCreate]);

if(result[0].success == "true"){
location.reload();
}
else{
alert(
"An Error has Occurred. Error: \r\n" +
result[0].errors.message
);
}
}
catch(e){
alert(
"An Un-expected Error has Occurred. Error: \r\n" +
e
);
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please, show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: above is the code